# How to set two chart in one row using anychart?

Tags: reactjs, anychart

I want to display two charts in one row I have applied chart.bounds() method still not working here my every chart is in different component and I am passing two component in a row like this way:

```
<Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Graph />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Demo />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
```

here Graph and Demo are not displaying in one row when I using react-bootstrap.

Comment: Please read [reprex]

Comment: There must be some css overriding the row/col styles. Provide more of your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As charts are placed in different containers, there's no need to apply `bounds()` settings to them. It's all about CSS setting for your  content.